# What is the moustache mode in Plants vs Zombies?

Tags: achievements, plants-vs-zombies

I saw an achievement in Plants vs Zombies which requires you to enable moustache mode(see below), but I have no clue what is it. Can somebody tell me how and what is exactly moustache mode?

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is only available on steam, requiring you to enter a "cheat code" to activate this. It does nothing, except turn on moustaches.

> To earn this achievement, the player must simply type "mustache" or "moustache" while playing the game or in the main menu, which will make some types of zombies have mustaches. If the player types it correctly, the achievement will be earned.

[Source](https://plantsvszombies.fandom.com/wiki/Ask_Me_About_Mustache_Mode)

Comment: I'd like to add that this "cheat code" is given to the player by the tree of wisdom, so there's an in-game way to find the code :)